# How to get the five last created users in order

Tags: linux

How do I get the five last created users in order?

I can sort them by userId with this command but is there a file where you can see the date when the user is created?

```
tail -5 /etc/passwd | sort -r | grep '/home' | cut -d: -f1
```

Comment: Maybe check the created date of the home directory for the user?

Comment: There is no creation date

rick@ubuntu:/home$ stat test
  File: `test'
  Size: 4096       Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 801h/2049d Inode: 927079      Links: 19
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1001/    test)   Gid: ( 1001/    test)
Access: 2013-11-21 16:22:00.667232451 +0100
Modify: 2013-11-21 15:34:49.907213906 +0100
Change: 2013-11-21 15:34:49.907213906 +0100
 Birth: -

Comment: I don't think it's possible to see the creation date without a mechanism to log user creations

Comment: I sorted them by userId now and I think I get the latest created first.
tail -5 /etc/passwd | sort -r -t':' -k3 | grep '/home' | cut -d: -f1

Comment: There are no guarantees that `/etc/passwd` is in any particular order, nor that UIDs/GIDs are assigned in any particular order, so unless you have an audit trail of `useradd` runs (and even that's dubious, as users can be created manually without using any utility), there's no way to do this...

Comment: @CDub most Linux file systems do not store a "created date". Common misconception - `ctime` is *change* time, not creation time.

Comment: http://linux.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/ubuntu-l/how-to-find-out-when-a-user-is-created-in-linux-4677888

Comment: look at all the files in the file system and sort the users by least recently modified files that they own. select the first 5?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the files in the system and sort the users based on the least recently modified files they own:

```
find /home | xargs -n 1 -I {} stat -c '%Y %U' "{}" | \
  awk '$1 < d[$2] || !d[$2] { d[$2]=$1 } \
      END{ for (u in d) { print d[u], u } }' | \
  sort -n -k1
```